# Google Analytics referring traffic to my site

Tags: google-analytics

This week I have seen 3 or 4 page referrals in Google Analytics coming from analytics.google.com.

First, I have my own IP sub net filtered via GA>Admin to prevent my own traffic appearing in GA.  Second, the URLs being accessed contain data/parameters that I know I didn't add.  The only thing that's changed has been a Chrome extension that I've added to block GA from tracking hits to my website when testing through VPNs and Chrome.

Should I be thinking about a possible security issue with the Chrome extension, or is there another possible explanation?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think these referrals are related to the Chrome extension or your own activity when you say the data/parameters are ones that you know you didn't add.  Is there some other reason that you think this might be self-traffic?